# Masking a 3D NumPy array --> returns 5D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, mask

I have a huge 3d NumPy array and a same shaped mask array filled with ones or zeros. Let's use this as an example:

```
arr = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(4, 4, 4))
mask = np.zeros(shape=(4,4,4), dtype='int')
mask[0,2:3,:] = 1
```

My goal is to get a same shaped array (in this example (4,4,4)), let's name it `new_arr`, with the values from `arr` where `mask == 1`. All other values in `new_arr` should get be `-2`. (not `0`)

However, doing this:

```
new_arr = arr[mask]
```

results in a (4, 4, 4, 4, 4) shaped array.

So, I've got pretty much 2 question: 1:) How do I get my desired result and 2.) Why does masking a 3d NumPy array this way result in a 5d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need np.where:

```
out = np.where(mask, arr, -2)
```

to answer your other question

2. Why does masking a 3d NumPy array this way result in a 5d array.

The idea is that `mask` has dtype `int`. So, `arr[mask]` actually works as slicing, not masking. So a `0` in `mask` would result in `arr[0]`, which is `(4,4)`. And then you do that for all values in `mask`, and you get an array with the same dimension of `mask` whose each value is a `(4,4)` array.

Another way to fix your code is:

```
out = np.full(arr.shape, -2)
out[mask.astype(bool)] = arr[mask.astype(bool)]
```